# Add task to front of push queue?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the java push queue API. I see there is an Queue.add() method which puts a task at the end:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue

is there a way to put a task at the front of the queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature by design & nature of queues (*not just AppEngine but in general*).

As a partial workaround you can use a separate "fast-lane" queue for tasks you want to prioritize. It can have higher rate then regular queue.

Also in some cases it can be beneficial to use "[delete task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/tasks/delete)" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I shared some thoughts on a similar problem recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580017/1836506

There are a couple other solutions on that question that may give you ideas, too.